# UIScrollView Lazy Loading Strategy With a Twist

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

I have a horizontally scrolling UIScrollview with paging enabled. Each page represents a data feed. Each data feed consumes a fairly large amount of memory including text and images displayed in a UITableView. Since the user can have an unlimited amount of data feeds, I need to lazy load them to prevent maxing out my memory usage. My thought is to keep up to 5 data feeds in memory at any given point, and release anything outside of that range. My initial take is to keep the page in the viewport in memory, and the 2 pages to either side of it. This way when the user scrolls, the next sequential page will always be in memory and will display quickly.

Here is my problem:
We also need to support a scenario where a user can skip to a specific data feed, possibly 10 or more pages to the right or left, which throws my entire lazy loading scheme out the window.

Might there be a better strategy to support this scenario?

Comment: The Apple HIG suggests three views in memory at a time. Do you add another one on each side to accommodate very quick scroll gestures?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, what you can do is create an outer scroll view, which houses individual cells akin to a tableview. In this respect, the cells have a content view which you can place your data, let's just assume you know how to do that since it seems you do.

Once you have this architecture in your mind, it becomes fairly clear: You can, knowing the width of your cells, and the size of the screen, some simple math can tell you how many you have on screen, and you can add one to the left or right so you're preloading some data for when the user scrolls.

This will say, give you the ability to have in memory, at most 5 feeds, if 3 are visible, at the start or end of the content view in the scrollview, 4 feeds, regardless of whether or not you have a billion feeds.

One critical part of this is cell reuse. You maintain a couple `NSSet`s, one for recycled cells, and one for visible cells. Add items that have gone off screen to the recycled cells, dequeue items from recycled cells when setting up the cell, as to save additional memory allocations, which can be expensive. Just remember, using this strategy, you are still subjective to the same caveats as a `UITableView` with respect to cell reuse.

I'm plugging some software I wrote here, so forgive me for that, but I'm doing so as an example of what I'm talking about if you get stuck implementing what I discussed here, it's available [here for your perusal](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/JScrollingRow).

One final note. To support skipping of cells, it's just simple math again to adjust the point in the scrollview you are at. The action for this can be done with a gesture, though now we're talking a pan gesture recognizer, with some specific properties that will be specific to your application, as an example. Or you can use buttons if you really must. Just ensure you know how to calculate your offsets to your cells, and scroll to that point. You'll be fine.

Comment: And NSSets are better than NSArrays why?

Comment: For this purpose, because lookup on an NSSet is O(1) operation, whereas in an NSArray it's O(n) where n = number of elements in the collection. Should not be surprising that lookup is faster on an NSSet, which is what we'll commonly be doing.

Comment: All 3 were awesome answers, and honestly, I was able to use ideas from each one. @jer, your example code pointed me in the right direction for implementation. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: No worries, glad it was of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give accurate advice with the information provided in the question. So I will just present a few thoughts I got when reading the question.

Does it take long to download a feed? Would it be possible to just download a few item (a screenful) to get the first few items showing right away? Perhaps lazy load the images if possible.

Have you considered caching the feed data on disk? That way you can present some data right away and then update the feed as new data gets downloaded.

Since each page is a feed view, would the user just scroll past a feed without looking at it? Do you really need to load 2 views on each side or can you get away with just 1 view on each side.

I don't think your lazy loading scheme stops working just because the user can skip directly to any page. You would have to start loading the data for that page when it is selected but by using a disk cache or downloading a small sample could make the app feel faster. I also think that using some kind of animation to animate to the selected page could buy you a little time.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my problem: We also need to support a scenario where a user can skip to a specific data feed, possibly 10 or more pages to the right or left, which throws my entire lazy loading scheme out the window.

Then you need to fix your data structure. I wrote pretty much exactly this (a UITableView-like paging scroll view) and it works fine (there are some reloading quirks, but hey...).

- Keep track of which pages you've loaded. I used a ring-buffer-alike modulo 8 and spent a while getting the code right; it's probably a lot easier to just use an NSDictionary with NSNumber keys and UIView values. This means when you change from page 1 to 10, you can still tell that the loaded views are for pages 1, 2, and 3, and drop them.
- Load the required pages in -layoutSubviews. I would load 1 or 3; 5 is probably too many (but you need to load at least 2 if you're between pages).
- Load 3 (one to either side) in `-scrollViewDidScroll:`. This is so that when you scroll from page 1 to 2, it doesn't try to load page 4 (which hasn't been loaded yet).
- Load 5 (two to either side) in `–scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` if willDecelerate is NO, `–scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`, `–scrollViewDidScrollToTop:`, and `–scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`. The idea is that the animation's over, so you can load the extra views without the user perceiving lag.
- Possibly load 5 in `–scrollViewWillBeginDragging:`, to make sure that page 3 is loaded if you're currently on page 1.

I decided to do "two pages either side" because when you flick from page 1 to page 2, it often shows a pixel-wide sliver of page 3 when it bounces. This can be avoided with scroll view insets, but we didn't think of that at the time (oops). There's otherwise not that much of a reason to choose 5 over 3.

It's a bit of work to get right, but otherwise seems to work flawlessly.